# Python googleapiclient of `kubectl get deployments`?

Tags: python, google-kubernetes-engine, google-api-client

I'm trying to move from cli kubernetes commands to Python-based google API to retreive information for my GKE clusters.

Specifically, I want to list all deployments. In kubectl I do this like this:

`kubectl get deployments`

I can't find online equivalents using the `googleapiclient/discovery`. Does anyone know what the preferref way is to accomplish this in Python?

I know I can fin information about my clusters like this:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'key.json')

service = discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
project = 'my-project'

request = service.projects().zones().clusters().list(projectId=project, zone='-')
response = request.execute()

if 'clusters' in response:
    for cluster in response['clusters']:
        print("%s,%s,%d" % (project, cluster['name'], cluster['currentNodeCount']))
        print("%s" % (cluster))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient
from kubernetes import client
import google.auth.transport.requests

project_id = "my-project"
zone = "my-zone"
cluster_id = "my-cluster"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file( 'key.json')

# Get GKE cluster details for the given cluster.
cluster_manager_client = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
cluster = cluster_manager_client.get_cluster(
        project_id=project_id, zone=zone,
        cluster_id=cluster_id)

# Get a token with the scopes required by GKE
kubeconfig_creds = credentials.with_scopes(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'])
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
kubeconfig_creds.refresh(auth_req)

#Client below is the k8s-client.
configuration = client.Configuration()

# the enpoint is an ip address, so we can't use the SSL verification :(
configuration.host = "https://"+cluster.endpoint+":443"
configuration.verify_ssl = False
kubeconfig_creds.apply(configuration.api_key)
client.Configuration.set_default(configuration)

#Use any kubernetes client methods, here I get all the deployments

deployments = client.AppsV1Api().list_deployment_for_all_namespaces()
for d in deployments.items:
   ...
```

Comment: I recommend using SSL - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68098831/714876

Comment: How will SSL *verification* work if the cluster-endpoint is an ip number?

Comment: Added info about this to my comment in the link!