# Unable to connect GKE autopilot cluster from kubernetes python client

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-python-client

I have created an Autopilot cluster on GKE

I want to connect and manage it with [Python Kubernetes Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python)

I am able to get the kubeconfig of cluster

I am able to access the cluster using kubectl on my local system using the command

> gcloud container clusters get-credentials

When I try to connect with python-client-library of kubernetes, I get following error

```
  File "lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', port=443): Max 
retries exceeded with url: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLError(136, '[X509] no certificate or crl found (_ssl.c:4140)')))
```

here is the code i am using

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "863924b908c7.json"

credentials, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', ])

credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())

cluster_manager = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
# cluster = cluster_manager.get_cluster(project)
config.load_kube_config('config.yaml')
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Comment: added the code...

Comment: can you share your config.yaml ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I figured out. I think it's a good solution because it prevents man in the middle attacks (uses SSL) unlike other python snippets in the wild.

```
from google.cloud.container_v1 import ClusterManagerClient
from kubernetes import client
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import base64
import google.auth

credentials, project = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',])
credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
cluster_manager = ClusterManagerClient(credentials=credentials)
cluster = cluster_manager.get_cluster(name=f"projects/{gcp_project_id}/locations/{cluster_zone_or_region}/clusters/{cluster_id}")

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as ca_cert:
 ca_cert.write(base64.b64decode(cluster.master_auth.cluster_ca_certificate))

config = client.Configuration()
config.host = f'https://{cluster.endpoint}:443'
config.verify_ssl = True
config.api_key = {"authorization": "Bearer " + credentials.token}
config.username = credentials._service_account_email
config.ssl_ca_cert = ca_cert.name
client.Configuration.set_default(config)

# make calls with client
```

> On GKE, SSL Validation works on the IP automatically. If you are in an environment where it doesn't work for some reason, you can bind the IP to a hostname list this:
>
> ```
> from python_hosts.hosts import (Hosts, HostsEntry)
> hosts = Hosts()
> hosts.add([HostsEntry(entry_type='ipv4', address=cluster.endpoint, names=['kubernetes'])])
> hosts.write()
> config.host = "https://kubernetes"
> ```